# Multiple browser instances in serenity

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

**Serenity version:** 2.6.0

I have a feature in my application in which to test the real time chat feature. I used to open two incognito mode to test it manually but when it comes to automation, I am not sure how to achieve this?

is there away to open two browser instance to test real time chatting in a single machine using **SERENITY**?

if not, kindly suggest the best approach to deal with this situation like selenium grid/sauce labs.

I tried open multiple browser instance by calling open() method back to back but it just replaces the other opened.

[image]

**Expected:**
Two browser instances need to be opened.

**Actual:**
One instance replaced the another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use two different actors to operate with separate browsers like this:

```
@Managed
WebDriver browser1;
@Managed
WebDriver browser2;

Actor user1 = Actor.named("user1");
Actor user2 = Actor.named("user2");

user1.whoCan(BrowseTheWeb.with(browser1));
user2.whoCan(BrowseTheWeb.with(browser2));

user1.attemptsTo(Open.browserOn().thePageNamed("http://gooogle.com"));
user2.attemptsTo(Open.browserOn().thePageNamed("http://gooogle.com"));
```

You can check [here](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/the-serenity-book/blob/master/modules/ROOT/pages/multi-browser-testing.adoc) too